# JavaScript add too var in object every frame not working

Tags: javascript, oop, createjs

So i have a object named Paddle and it has a var in it called posX and for some reason i cant just add one to it every frame but i can set its value, here is my coed

https://jsfiddle.net/noig/s9yxx13q/

```
var Paddle = function(sizeX, sizeY){
    var posX, posY;
    var sizeX, sizeY;

    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;

    this.shape = new createjs.Shape();
}

Paddle.prototype.update = function(){
    this.shape.x = this.posX;
};

var paddle1 = new Paddle(25, 75);

function init(){

    var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

    //shape = new createjs.Shape();
    paddle1.shape.graphics.beginFill("blue").drawRect( 15, 0, paddle1.sizeX, paddle1.sizeY);

    stage.addChild(paddle1.shape);

    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', stage);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', update);
}

function update(){
    //paddle1.update(); This runs the code to make shape.x = posX

    //paddle1.shape.x++; This moves paddle 1 every frame when not useing paddle.update();
    //paddle1.posX = 50; This moves to the paddel50 units with paddle1.update();
    //paddle1.posX++; This dose not move the paddle 1 unit every frame
    //paddle1.posX += 1; This dose not move the paddle 1 unit ever frame
    //paddle1.posX = paddle1.posX + 1; This dose not move the paddle 1 unit every frame
}

init();
```

Comment: I might be missing something... but `posX` is never defined as a public variable. `this.posX` should solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to update `this.shape.x` when you set `this.posX`. One way to do that is to define a property with getter/setter. Try adding this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Paddle.prototype, "posX", {
  get: function() {return this.shape.x},
  set: function(x) { this.shape.x = x; }
});
Object.defineProperty(Paddle.prototype, "posY", {
  get: function() {return this.shape.y},
  set: function(y) { this.shape.y = y; }
});
```

```js
var Paddle = function(sizeX, sizeY){
    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
    this.shape = new createjs.Shape();   
}

Object.defineProperty(Paddle.prototype, "posX", {
  get: function() {return this.shape.x},
  set: function(x) { this.shape.x = x;  }
});
Object.defineProperty(Paddle.prototype, "posY", {
  get: function() {return this.shape.y},
  set: function(y) { this.shape.y = y; }
});

var paddle1 = new Paddle(25, 75);

function init(){

    var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

    //shape = new createjs.Shape();
    paddle1.shape.graphics.beginFill("blue").drawRect( 15, 0, paddle1.sizeX, paddle1.sizeY);

    stage.addChild(paddle1.shape);

    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', stage);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', update);
}

function update(){
    paddle1.posX++; 
}

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.05.21.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank You so much, i was trying to find out how to get and set in JavaScript because C# has a way of simplifying it ex, int thing { get; set;}